# Can a let binding assign to a mutable variable rather than shadowing?

Tags: rust, variable-assignment

I have some code that looks like this:

```
let mut x = ...;
while let Some(x_) = foo(x) {
    x = x_;
    bar(x);
}
baz(x);
```

I'd like to write it as:

```
let mut x = ...;
while let Some(x) = foo(x) {
    bar(x);
}
baz(x);
```

but as far as I know this will shadow the outer mutable `x` instead of assigning to it. Note that I need access to the final value of `x` after the loop ends.

Comment: I don't think so, I think the first code is how it's supposed to be. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I'd just like to reduce verbosity. The real code is destructuring a more complex struct, and there are multiple boilerplate variable-copying lines.

Comment: You could wrap all of those variables in a struct. You can assign multiple values in the same line. There are many improvements, but none of them are related to directly destructuring an enum into an outer variable. I don't think it's possible right now.

Comment: Related discussion: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-allow-existing-variables-in-destructuring-tuples/10970/5 It's not completely related, but a previous step. So if this isn't possible yet, I don't think performing it conditionally is or will be possible anytime soon. But again, I'm sure there are other ways to optimize the code, just not in the way you asked.

Comment: Related: you can destructure when assigning as shown here [Can I destructure a tuple without binding the result to a new variable in a let/match/for statement?](/a/71261230/2189130) but not in a `let`.

Comment: I'd be nice if `while Some(x) = foo(x)` worked, but currently it [crashes the compiler](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9144a1f11298b91af386dc024b8679e1) ... Maybe in a future version something like this would be possible. For now you could always create a macro for it.

Comment: [Destructuring assignments](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2909) were merged in Rust 1.59.0, but that does not cover `let`, `while let`, or `if let`. So you're still out of luck here.

Answer (score 2):

No, `let` always binds a new variable, even when inside of `if` or `while`. The only way to reassign the value of an existing variable is with the infix `=` operator.